# Multi-ring buffer (Constant distance) selecting features in another layer

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have used the multi-ring buffer to form a buffer area of 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 metres from a road. However I am struggling to select features from another layer (trails). My aim is to count all the trails within 10 metres of the road then 20 metres from the road and so on.

However I cant seem to do this as I select the 10 metre region of the buffer for example and the only feature highlighted is the buffer zone it self.

Comment: Have you tried **Select by location** tool? If you first select 10 metre buffer and start this tool, it allows you to use `Selected features only` option.